# Dynamics Email Marketing Template Editor is Overriding Custom CSS

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm attempting to apply custom CSS to a blank email template in Dynamics' Email Marketing template editor. I inserted a code block into the template that has the following:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
            background: #ececec;
        }

        p.MsoNormal {
            line-height: 25px !important;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
```

(The attributes shown above are just for testing purposes.)

The problem I'm encountering is when I do a test send, some of the CSS is not being applied. The source of the email contains inline styling that overrides my CSS:

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman";text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>
```

In the head of the email source, I can see that SOME of my CSS is being recognized and integrated into the document's style definitions (specifically, text-decoration):

```
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:18.75pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-underline:single;}
```

And I can also confirm that the webfont is being applied.

Am I applying custom CSS incorrectly? If not, other than building out emails entirely in the HTML editor, is there a way to reliably apply custom CSS without it being overridden with inline styles?